# print the date in specific format

Tags: date

We want to print the log in bash script with the following date format

```
 2018-03-22 09:54:05,$task   ( $task is a counter of command )

 echo " `date +% .... ,$task` INFO $1"   ( $1 is the $1 argument that we want to print )
```

example

```
 2018-03-22 09:54:05,001 INFO script begin to start server
 2018-03-22 09:54:05,001 INFO script begin to start agent
```

Comment: What have you tried? The `date` manpage lists the various formatting directives it supports.

Comment: echo " `date +%G"-"%d"-"%H` "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `echo` in this instance:

```
date +"%F %T,$task INFO $1"
```

If `$task` or `$1` contains `%`, then these has to be replaced with `%%` first so that they are not interpreted as format sequences by `date`.  This could be done in `bash` with

```
date +"%F %T,${task//%/%%} INFO ${1//%/%%}"
```

Answer (score 2):

From [`man date`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/date.1.html):

```
%F     full date; same as %Y-%m-%d
%T     time; same as %H:%M:%S
```